# When to use prepare_data vs setup in pytorch lightning?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

[Pytorch's docs](https://import%20pytorch_lightning%20as%20pl%20from%20torch.utils.data%20import%20random_split,%20DataLoader%20%20#%20Note%20-%20you%20must%20have%20torchvision%20installed%20for%20this%20example%20from%20torchvision.datasets%20import%20MNIST%20from%20torchvision%20import%20transforms%20%20%20class%20MNISTDataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):%20%20%20%20%20def%20__init__(self,%20data_dir:%20str%20=%20%22./%22):%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super().__init__()%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.data_dir%20=%20data_dir%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.transform%20=%20transforms.Compose(%5Btransforms.ToTensor(),%20transforms.Normalize((0.1307,),%20(0.3081,))%5D)%20%20%20%20%20%20def%20prepare_data(self):%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20#%20download%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20MNIST(self.data_dir,%20train=True,%20download=True)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20MNIST(self.data_dir,%20train=False,%20download=True)%20%20%20%20%20%20def%20setup(self,%20stage:%20Optional%5Bstr%5D%20=%20None):%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20#%20Assign%20train/val%20datasets%20for%20use%20in%20dataloaders%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20stage%20==%20%22fit%22%20or%20stage%20is%20None:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mnist_full%20=%20MNIST(self.data_dir,%20train=True,%20transform=self.transform)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.mnist_train,%20self.mnist_val%20=%20random_split(mnist_full,%20%5B55000,%205000%5D)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20#%20Assign%20test%20dataset%20for%20use%20in%20dataloader(s)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20stage%20==%20%22test%22%20or%20stage%20is%20None:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.mnist_test%20=%20MNIST(self.data_dir,%20train=False,%20transform=self.transform)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20stage%20==%20%22predict%22%20or%20stage%20is%20None:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.mnist_predict%20=%20MNIST(self.data_dir,%20train=False,%20transform=self.transform)%20%20%20%20%20%20def%20train_dataloader(self):%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20DataLoader(self.mnist_train,%20batch_size=32)%20%20%20%20%20%20def%20val_dataloader(self):%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20DataLoader(self.mnist_val,%20batch_size=32)%20%20%20%20%20%20def%20test_dataloader(self):%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20DataLoader(self.mnist_test,%20batch_size=32)%20%20%20%20%20%20def%20predict_dataloader(self):%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20DataLoader(self.mnist_predict,%20batch_size=32)) on Dataloaders only say, in the code

```
def prepare_data(self):
    # download
    ...
```

and

```
def setup(self, stage: Optional[str] = None):
    # Assign train/val datasets for use in dataloaders
```

Please explain the intended separation between `prepare_data` and `setup`, what callbacks may occur between them, and why put something in one over the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the pseudo for the [`Trainer.fit`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/trainer.html?highlight=fit#fit) function provided in the documentation page of [`LightningModule`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/lightning_module.html) at [**§ Hooks**](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/lightning_module.html#hooks), you can read:

```
def fit(self):
    if global_rank == 0:
        # prepare data is called on GLOBAL_ZERO only
        prepare_data()                                 ## <-- prepare_data

    configure_callbacks()

    with parallel(devices):
        # devices can be GPUs, TPUs, ...
        train_on_device(model)


def train_on_device(model):
    # called PER DEVICE
    on_fit_start()
    setup("fit")                                       ## <-- setup
    configure_optimizers()

    # the sanity check runs here

    on_train_start()
    for epoch in epochs:
        fit_loop()
    on_train_end()

    on_fit_end()
    teardown("fit")
```

You can see `prepare_data` being called only for `global_rank == 0`, *i.e.* it is only called by a single processor. It turns out you can read from the documentation description of [`prepare_data`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/lightning_module.html#prepare-data):

> `LightningModule.prepare_data()`
> Use this to download and prepare data. Downloading and saving data with multiple processes (distributed settings) will result in corrupted data. ***Lightning ensures this method is called only within a single process, so you can safely add your downloading logic within***.

Whereas [`setup`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/lightning_module.html#setup) is called on all processes as you can read from the pseudo-code above as well as its documentation description:

> `LightningModule.setup(stage=None)`
> Called at the beginning of fit (train + validate), validate, test, or predict. This is a good hook when you need to build models dynamically or adjust something about them. This ***hook is called on every process when using DDP***.

Comment: This is a great answer. What I am now missing, is why [my linked doc] is doing train/val split on `setup` time, rather than on `prepare_data` time? It would make sense to only do that once. Should the separation be based only on what can be parallelized?

Comment: Each rank needs to see the same train/val split. If you do that split in memory, you need to use setup because all ranks need to end up with the same split! If you prefer to do the split once and save it to disk, then you can use prepare_data. But usually the split is done at runtime, which is why setup is recommended for this.

Comment: If you perform the split in `setup`, wouldn't you generally end up with different splits in different processes?

Comment: @Ben I think you can fix the `seed` to control the splits.